# hitTest returns null when ctrl/shift/alt is held targeting an already preselected subassembly

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

While calling `hitTest` on an already preselected group of nodes, meaning, nodes in parent/child relationship preselected previously using `select`, and at the same time, holding down either shift, alt or ctrl the `hitTest` call returns `null`.

Is there another way to get `dbId` of a node from a preselected subgroup of nodes under cursor when a modifier (shift, alt, ctrl) key is held down?

```js
    private getDbIdAtCoords(x: number, y: number) {
        const viewport = this.viewerWrapper.viewer.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        const result = this.viewerWrapper.viewer.impl.hitTest(
            x - viewport.left,
            y - viewport.top,
            false,
        );
        return result ? result.dbId : 0;
    }
    ...
    this.viewer.canvas.onclick = evt => {
        this.getDbIdAtCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need to hold down those keys? is it for multiselection? Also please share the image when you're clicking and doing hitTest

Comment: Yes, the reason is multiselection. For now, I kind of got around the issue by letting regular selection, that means without any modifier key being held down, buffer all the selections. In order to then deselect a group of nodes, the user has a UI menu with list of selected groups available via which they can toggle those selections.

Comment: Thanks for the response, may I consider it resolved by a workaround by the author?

Comment: I cannot tell cause the customer, I'm doing the project for, might not like the workaround. To me it's ok, even when I find it strange that `hitTest` does not work when modifier key is held down and previously selected group of nodes is the hit target. Thank you, anyway, @varunpatil.

Comment: shift and option, worked, but cntrl un selected the selected object, let's look into it over zoom call if you're okay with it. Please book your session here: https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services/varunpatil